# Laravel login return false for some users with correct credentials

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

My authController used to work perfectly, but recently something changed. I'm not sure what caused this change, but for some users it's no longer possible to sign into my application.

Returning `unauthorised`

I haven't changed anything to my code, but I am running my database with `MySql` and `valet`, and have yesterday installed `phpmyadmin`

What I expect to happend is that all my users can login in with correct credentials

What is happening that some (tested with creating a new user and trying to sign in) users can't sign in (definitely all the new users)

**AuthController**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Role;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name'     => $request->name,
            'email'    => $request->email,
            'adress'   => 'Enter your adress',
            'sex'      => $request->sex,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);
        $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'user')->first());
        $token = auth()->login($user);
        $signedInUser = \Auth::user();
        $signedInUserStore = \Auth::user()->stores;

        return $signedInUser;
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $token = User::find($id);
        $token->name = Request::input('name');
        $token->email = Request::input('email');
        $token->email = Request::input('email');
        $token->save();

        return $this->respondWithToken($token);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only(['email', 'password']);
        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
        }
        $signedInUser = \Auth::user();
        $signedInUserStore = \Auth::user()->stores;

        return $this->respondWithToken($token, $signedInUser, $signedInUserStore);
    }

    protected function respondWithToken($token, $signedInUser, $signedInUserStore)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'user'         => $signedInUser,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type'   => 'bearer',
            'expires_in'   => auth()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How come you're not using the builtin auth? Looking at your code, I can see that you're not validating the request data. Can you conform that `email` and `password` are definitely in the request i.e. `dd($credentials)`?

Comment: I'm actually new to laravel, and actually took over the code from someone else who was working on it. Not sure how the validation works, but it did use to legit work

Comment: Ok. At this point there are multiple different reasons why the login might not be working anymore. The first thing I would check is that you can manually create a user and then log that user in using something like `php artisan tinker`. If you can then I would check that you're definitely submitting the correct data when you're creating a new user.

Comment: The register controller that ships with laravel Auth uses `'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])` not bcrypt() like in your code

Comment: @dparoli Unless the user has changed the default hash driver, `Hash::make()` will be using the `BCRYPT` anyway.